# TF237121: Cannot complete the operation. An unexpected error occurred

Tags: tfsbuild, full-text-search

When I run my application that has been deployed on the server, I get this error message when a query to TFS is made. For example, obtain a Project Collection or Work Items. I do not get this error locally, and the server does not have Visual Studio 2010 installed and so I have to set `Copy Local` to `true` for every needed .dll... What causes this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I resolved the issue using the method described [here](http://berg-henry.blogspot.ca/2010/07/connecting-to-tfs2010-from-webpart.html).

**web.config**

```
<appSettings> <!-- Add reference to TFS Client Cache -->
   <add key="WorkItemTrackingCacheRoot" value="C:\TFSClientCache" /> </appSettings>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to clear folder content from C:\TFSClientCache and then it started working.